# Display list item over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-easing

I have a menu bar, whose menu `li` stretch down on mouse hover. It pushes sidewards a `div` below this menu bar div. But I want those stretch down `li`s to display over the mentioned div, without pushing it sidewards.

You can have a look at what I am trying to tell [here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Gvn3U/).

Anybody got a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bpu2r/

I've simply added `float: left;` to the menu and `clear: both;` to the container.